# How to have host machine postgres data in docker container using volumes?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have some data in my host machine which I want the container to use. I can do this by taking dump from my host machine and ingesting the same while postgres is starting in the container. But this is not how I wanted it to be.

I'm trying to leverage docker volumes to be able to use host machine data in container so whenever any new data is added or removed to postgres on container it should also reflect on the host machine.

Here's my `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
version: '3.2'

services:
      postgresql:
        image: postgres:9.6.8
        ports:
          - '5432:5432'
        volumes:
          - /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

`/var/lib/postgresql/data` is the default PGDATA location in official postgres docker image.

With the above `docker-compose.yml` file and trying with multiple volume mappings, I'm unable to find host machine data in container.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to mount `/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/data` instead of `/main`?

Comment: There's no `/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/data` in host PGDATA actually.

Comment: What system are you using?

Comment: @trust512 I use Ubuntu 16.04 and the version of Postgres is same on both host and container.

Comment: could you provide `ls -al` from the host location your are mapping to? (as a edit to your question) Because contents of your `main/` might not be what Postgres expects from `pgdata`

Comment: Here it is @trust512 https://gist.github.com/waseem18/b0595bb2f8150ee593c70d002211cc3b

Comment: And did you check if inside the postgres container, in the specified location, there actually is all the data that is supposed to be mapped there? The host contents are fine. ( I mean `ls -al` from the `/var/lib/postgresql/data` inside the container )